# Angular Service abstraction with flexible NgModule providers & conditional dependency loading

Tags: angular

I am writing an Angular library module and want a flexible configuration while making it as easy as possible to use in a consuming app, support both eager and lazy loading, and load as fast as possible.

The idea is to create and expose some web components (the bulk of the library), and (optionally) a service which is a default implementation used to get data to power these components from a reference API server. The goal is to let the user use the components with or without the default service, and/or inject their own service implementation that the components should use instead. At the same time, it should not load unused dependencies (e.g. if the app wants to inject a custom service that does not use Http calls, then the Http module should not need to be imported).

I've posted below what I have so far. My questions are:

1. is this a reasonable way to go about doing this or am I overcomplicating?
2. when using the default library service implementation (application-default.ts below), I will need to inject a Http provider somewhere. Is there any way I can dynamically import the Http module only in this case (i.e.  when using the included default service) without requiring the consuming app to have to know to include it in its imports definition?

library.ts

```js
abstract class ServiceImplementation {
}

@Injectable()
export class DefaultServiceImplementation extends ServiceImplementation {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    doSomething() {
        return this.http.get(...);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: ''
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(@Optional() private service: ServiceImplementation) {
        if(service) {
            service.doSomething().subscribe(...);
        }
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // AngularDependanciesRequiredOnlyForMyComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        MyComponent
    ]
})
export class LibraryModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LibraryModule,
            providers: [
                { provide: ServiceImplementation, useClass: DefaultServiceImplementation }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

application-provide.ts - Using the library but providing a custom service.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceImplementation extends ServiceImplementation {
    doSomething() {
        return Observable.of(...);
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LibraryModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: ServiceImplementation, useClass: MyServiceImplementation }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

application-default.ts - Using the library supplied service

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LibraryModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this i also implement on our product. It makes sense to create a "service" abstraction. 
I don´t know if its possible to add dynamically modules like Http or FormModule. IMHO its not need to think about to import HttpModule or not, because on AOT - Build the angular-cli will drop unused elements.

I have an implementation to load and import flat es modules into our application, but this is a different thing.